# Heap Space Issue while Running a Pig Script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, heap-memory

I am trying to execute a pig script with around 30 million data and I am getting the below heap space error:

```
> ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Java heap space
> 
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>         at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
>         at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
>         at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
>         at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
>         at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.shiftStringByTabs(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:223)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:108)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:102)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:102)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:102)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:102)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:102)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:102)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:102)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirst(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:102)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.depthFirstLP(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:83)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanPrinter.visit(LogicalPlanPrinter.java:69)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LogicalPlan.getLogicalPlanString(LogicalPlan.java:148)
>         at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LogicalPlan.getSignature(LogicalPlan.java:133)
>         at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1295)
>         at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:375)
>         at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:353)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
>         at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
>         at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:607)
>         at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
> ================================================================================
```

I ran the same code with 10 million data and it ran fine.

> > So what are the possible ways I can avoid the above issue?
> >     Does compression helps in avoiding the heap space issue?
> >                                                                        I have tried to split the code into multiple fragments and still I am getting
> >     the error.So even though if we increase the heap memeory alloaction does it gurantee it will hold true if we execute the same with volume
> >     of data?

Comment: Which mode you ran you code ,Local or mapreduce..Just a intital thought..

Comment: Can  you try with mapreduce mode...and check if the same problem arises in cluster mode aswel

Answer (score 1):

You can increase numbers of mappers by setting mapred.map.tasks to any number you want. and than run your script.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for that could be you have a giantic line in your data that doesn't fit into memory.

So try to check. You can run this bash command in a node of your cluster:

```
hdfs dfs -cat '/some/path/to/hdfs.file' | awk '{if (length($0) > SOME_VALUE_REASONABLE_VALUE) print $0}' > large_lines
```

If your data is not in a single file you can use `*`, for example `/some/path/to/hdfs.dir/part*`.

Then you should check if there are some huge lines:

```
less large_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are appending some data into a globalStringBuilder variable, either to get a summary of the results or to get some logs.

If you need some output, just log/get a summary of the first x lines.