# How to set PIG_HEAPSIZE in a cloudera cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have a pig script which is going out of memory every time I run from Oozie.

Error:

Pig logfile dump:

### Pig Stack Trace

ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Java heap space

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:387)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:956)
```

I have tried set numerous parameters but without any success.

Same pig script runs from command line if I export PIG_HEAPSIZE = 4000.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065622/heap-space-issue-while-running-a-pig-script

Comment: @ArunakiranNulu I have tired various combinations , but none have worked , I need a pin point solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done easily by adding these two lines in Oozie(Workflow.xml) script:

```
<property>
     <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.child.java.opts</name>
     <value>-server -Xmx4G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</value>
</property>
```

:)